# Any way to jump to a much older point in a Facebook photo stream?

Tags: facebook, facebook-photos, user-interface

When you go to the Photos section of a Facebook page, the URL will be `https://www.facebook.com/PAGENAME/photos_stream`, and then as you keep scrolling down, more photos will appear.

This one Facebook page I am looking at seems to have thousands (maybe even tens of thousands) of photos.  I want to see the photos from a few years ago, but it might take me several hours to scroll down that far.

Is there any way to jump to another point in the photo stream?  If the photo stream had a page-based navigation with a certain number of photos per page, then I might be able to manipulate the URL with something like `https://www.facebook.com/PAGENAME/photos_stream?page=5000` to jump to a much further point in the photo stream.  But the Facebook photo stream isn't page-based, so that won't work.  Is there anything else I can try?